# Excel 2007 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").Select

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know why my Select for the Range don't work on this line.
It's the right syntax for range.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report M-1").Select
ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Find("Operational  Categorization Tier 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="SECURITY TROUBLE"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

If FeuilleExiste("Feuil1") = False Then
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
End If

****ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1:").Select****
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'suppression filtre
 Workbooks("Monthly security report May.xls").Activate
 ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").AutoFilter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1:").Select****

You have an extra `:` in the range.

It should be

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").Select
```

BTW you should avoid the use of `.Select`. You might want to see [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: You could just create a comment for that change.

Comment: @Makah: I could and I have done it in the past but comments are temporary :) And hence it is good to leave an answer. Feel free to downvote it if you disagree...